# Why is Xcode constraints doing this to my app?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode7

[image: Screenshot of my issue]

[image: Screenshot of the "=" button constraints]

Can somebody please help me understand why the Xcode auto layout constraints keep cutting the bottom buttons?
All the buttons heights are 50 and for some reason any button on the bottom gets cut. (I have shown a screenshot of my screen)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: just remove that bottom constraints from bottom view and give fix height ... this will solve your issue

Comment: Can you provide another screenshot showing details of the constraint you have with the equal button and the bottom of your view?

Comment: @dokun1 i just added another screenshot to clarify things

Comment: @EICaptain can you please elaborate how i would achieve this im sorry im a little bit new to xcode and thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comment you need to remove bottom constraint from button something like this image ... select constraint and delete it and than add height constraint

[image]

So now your constraints would be `top , leading , trailing and fixed height`

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you very much and sorry for the such basic question but like i said im a newbie..

Answer (score 1):

The `=` button should set its `height = 50` instead of set the constraint to the `bottom` of `super view` .

Remove `Bottom space to: Bottom Layout Guide`. Then drag the `=` button like this

[image]

Then choose height

[image]

and edit it to 50.

Comment: okay i understand but can you please elaborate how i would do this in Xcode..sorry im new kind of new to this...

Comment: Ok. I attach an image for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

You should not give bottom constraint in this case. your button's constraint should be like,

`leading, trailing, top and fix height`

Comment: You're welcome...:) If you feel that it is helping then accept the answer so other people with similar issue can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong Constraint: `"Bottom space to ...."`.
In your case, the "=" button's height is NOT fixed.

You should change this constraint to `"Height Equals: 50"` or equals to another button.

---

The last, excuse me for any mistakes since my not-so-good English.